# What is the name of $\mathscr{C}(X) $?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, pronunciation

One thing that I hate about Baby Rudin is that the author doesn’t name the theorems after mathematicians; instead, he uses numbers (3.37,4.15 , etc ), and I think it is easier to remember if he uses names.

> **Definition 7.14** If $X$ is a metric space, $\mathscr{C}(X) $ will denote the set of all complex-valued, continuous, bounded functions with domain $X$.

I want to ask, what is the name of $\mathscr{C}(X)$? Does it have a name like other spaces (Hilbert space, measure space, etc.) or not?

Another question is: Is $\mathscr{C}$ a 'C' or an 'L' or '$\varphi$' ?

Comment: Sometimes they are called the ring of continuous functions. But their definition is much more general.

Comment: It doesn't have a name besides continuous bounded functions, and it is a C.

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't look like a C. Before I wrote this question I thought it was an L but the code \mathscr{C} what made me realise it was a C

Comment: The name is "$C$ of $X$".  Really.  People pronounced $C([0,1])$ as "$C$ of $0$ $1$".

Comment: Are we starting to see the results of young students not learning cursive?

Comment: Most serious text in mathematics don’t name the theorems and results they present most of the time but only number them, with the exception of a few extremely famous and important ones. Even if names are used, you’ll only remember the names, not the actual content.

Comment: @Divide1918 It will be much easier for the reader to say ‘by L’Hôpital’s rule than ‘by theorem 4.18’

Comment: @Mathematicsenjoyer You just cherrypicked an example with a name, when I had literally said “with the exception of…”. Names only work when there are so few theorems.